# Upgrade JSF 2.0 project facet to JSF 2.1 in RAD 8.5

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere, websphere-8

I have IBM RAD 8.5.1 and WAS 8.5 server on my desktop. When I try to create a Dynamic Web Project in wizard, in the Configuration drop down menu there is only JSF 2.0 available in project facets. I want to upgrade this to 2.1. How can I install or upgrade the JSF project facet to 2.1?

Comment: I believe that when you select the JSF 2.0 project Facet that you have the opportunity later in the wizard to download or choose your own library.  You can bundle the 2.1.x jars into a User Library and add them in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to. Just supply JSF 2.1 libraries and you're all set. There's nothing new in JSF 2.1 which would require new IDE magic to make the job easier. JSF 2.2 however does (Faces Flows, etc), but that's not your current concern. The project facet versions merely tell the IDE which features it should recognize and offer the appropriate wizards (the "magic") for. It doesn't cause the ultimately built/deployed webapp to run in some kind of fallback modus or so. You've after all  still 100% control over the code.

Comment: Thank you for your helps. I can add jsf 2.1.x as a user library and go on.